# Import public key from trusted root CA to PKCS12 key store

Tags: certificate, keystore, pkcs#12

How do I import a public key from trusted root CA to PKCS12 key store?

Is this possible at all or am I getting the idea of this whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PKCS#12 file can contain various objects, but usually it contains certificates and private keys. A certificate is a container for a public key and other things, including a signature.

A root CA is often represented as a certificate (with a dummy signature, traditionally a self-signature). What makes such a certificate a "root CA" is a programmatic property, in which an application or an operating system declares: "in this certificate I trust".

It is possible to store a root CA certificate in a PKCS#12 file. What cannot be done is to store it as a "root": the certificate goes in the file, not the property which declares that the certificate is to be trusted *ex nihilo*. In more details, PKCS#12 is an open format but if you want to store something in a PKCS#12 file and have it read properly on the other end, then there must exist some sort of convention on how the object bits are to be interpreted. Such a convention does not exist (yet) for PKCS#12 files and trust settings.

You do not state which language you are using; I am assuming Java. In Java, there is a `KeyStore` class, obtained with a given "type", one of them being "pkcs12". You may then find, in the JCA documentation (in "Key Management"), the following:

*As of JDK 6, standards for storing Trusted Certificates in "pkcs12" have not been established yet, and thus "jks" or "jceks" should be used for trusted certificates.*

which says it all.

Comment: the problem is I am trying to Encrypt a mail using this http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/ and when I try to import sth else then a pkcs12 keystore I get following exception:
java.io.IOException: stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store

Comment: for those who are interessted - i found this tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/ and i does exactly what i want :D

Comment: If you can see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606281/how-to-add-pfx-certificate-file-in-keystore-using-android-2-3-3) and answer if possible. I dont know i should comment this here or not, but i found this topic similar to my problem and i really need help thats why i commented here. I hope no one will have any objection on it.